# Sum of a Column with Distinct Row id in HTML TABLE with jquery or JS Example is below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jquery or JS help Regarding HTML TABLE

below is HTML TABLE

[image: Snap Short of The HTML TABLE IS HERE]

[image: Likw this i want result plz Click to see it.]

Comment: Needed Result in another HTMLtable

Comment: You should add your html and what tried you.

Comment: i tryed but did not get anything in my hand. and i am not that much familiar with JS and Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var id=[];
 $('#test tbody tr').each(function(){
if($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text()!= ""
  &&
id.indexOf($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text()) == -1
)
{
id.push($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text())
}
});
objNewTable="";
for(i=0;i<id.length;i++)
{
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == id[i] ;
}).closest("tr");


sum=0;
$(tableRow).each(function(){
sum = sum + parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text(), 10);

});

objNewTable =objNewTable + "<tr><td>" + (i+1) + "</td><td>" +$(tableRow).find(':eq(1)').html()+ "</td><td>" +$(tableRow).find(':eq(2)').html()+ "</td><td>" + sum  + "</td></tr>"
}

$('#result').html(objNewTable )

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id='result'>
</html>
<table id='test'>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Member Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
  </tr>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AB3550</td>
    <td>Rohan</td>
    <td>500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>    
    <td>AB3856</td>
    <td>Ruchit</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>    
    <td>AB3550</td>
    <td>Rohan</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>AB3550</td>
    <td>Rohan</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>AB3856</td>
    <td>Ruchit</td>
    <td>500</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry,i am new &  Right now i am not Eligible to Vote anybody. i will Vote u as soon i become  Eligible  for Vote.